# Diffusion Equation with Neumann conditions on unit sphere

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have the following PDE in $B_{1} = \{\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3 : |\mathbf{x}| < 1\}$

$\begin{cases} u_{t} = \Delta u, \hspace{18mm} \mathbf{x} \in B_{1}, t > 0 \\
u(\mathbf{x}, 0) = |\mathbf{x}|,  \hspace{10mm} \mathbf{x} \in B_{1} \\
u_{\nu} (\mathbf{\sigma} , t) = 1, \hspace{11.8mm} \mathbf{\sigma} \in \partial B_{1}, t > 0 \end{cases}$

I start by assuming the solution is radially symmetric and with $|\mathbf{x}| = r$. I convert the PDE to be in terms of $r$ and $t$, giving me

$\begin{cases} u_{t} - \frac{1}{r} (ru)_{rr} = 0, \hspace{10mm} 0 < r < 1, t > 0 \\
u(r,0) = r, \hspace{21.7mm} 0 < r < 1 \\
u_{r}(1,t) = 1, \hspace{20.5mm} t > 0\end{cases}$

After this I want homogeneous boundary conditions, so I let $v(r,t) = u(r,t) - r$. This will then give me

$\begin{cases} v_{t} - \frac{1}{r} (rv)_{rr} = \frac{2}{r}, \hspace{10mm} 0 < r < 1, t > 0 \\
v(r,0) = 0, \hspace{22.3mm} 0 < r < 1 \\
v_{r} (1,t) = 0, \hspace{21mm} t > 0 \end{cases}$

Now that I have the PDE reduced to this, I want to use separation of variables. This is where I start thinking something has gone wrong, though.

$v(r,t) = R(r) T(t)$ gives me $T(0) = 0$, $\frac{dR(1)}{dr} = 0$ and the system

$\frac{1}{T} \cdot \frac{dT}{dt} = \frac{1}{rR} \cdot \frac{d^2 (rR)}{dr^2} = \lambda$

I don't think this works, though. If I assume my solution must be bounded, then the ODE with respect to $r$ gave me the eigenfunctions $\frac{\sin (\mu_{n} r)}{r}$ where $\mu_{n}$ are the positive solutions to $\tan \mu = \mu$. But if I consider the ODE with respect to $t$, I would have

$\frac{dT}{dt} = \lambda T$. For $\lambda = 0$, $T = \alpha$, a constant. But then $T(0) = 0$ gives $T = 0$.

For $\lambda \neq 0$, $T = c e^{\lambda t}$, which would again give $T = 0$ after applying $T(0) = 0$.

So what's going on? Am I even on the right track with this problem so far? Things seemed to be working out okay until this issue with $T \equiv 0$, so any help would be much appreciated!